# Can I see the currently checked out revision number in Tortoise SVN?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I'd like to know what the currently checked out revision number is for a file or directory. Is there a way to do this in TortoiseSVN on Windows ?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Right-click on the working directory in windows explorer, and select "Properties" (Not TortoiseSVN->Properties).  You will see the Properties dialog, which will have a tab called "Subversion".  Click on it, and you will see the version number, and other info.

Comment: Strange...  I have used in on Windows Server 2003 and 2008, both 64-bit.  Are you sure that you have Tortoise installed?  Can you see the Tortoise icons showing the status of the versioned files?

Comment: "Properties" is not the TortoiseSVN properties but the usual Windows explorer properties.

Comment: To my understanding the displayed version number corresponds to the last svn update (or svn checkout if there was no svn update afterwards). Any svn commit which has been applied on the local directory afterwards is ignored. In order to see the 'last' revision number of any update or commit see the answer of @nishantcop: Bold line in TortoiseSVN Log. (Tested on Windows 10, TortoiseSVN 1.13.1, Subversion 1.13.0)

Answer (score 22):

Not in tortoise but in command line.

```
svn info
```

will return what rev you are checked out on.

Comment: I'll +1 on this answer because this SO-answer is returned by google when I searched for "svn currently checked out revision". And you answered at least that ;-)

Comment: It tells you a revision number, but not whether that revision is the HEAD or not.  For that I think you need to use `svnlook youngest /var/svn/xyz` on the raw repository path... surely an easier way to see whether you are at HEAD?

Answer (score 18):

*TortoiseSVN -> Show log*: The line in **bold** marks the current revision in your working copy.

Comment: while the accepted answer is the fastest one, this seems to be the "canonical TSVN answer" ;)

Comment: To do the same thing from command line use: `svn -r HEAD info --show-item last-changed-revision`

Answer (score 9):

If you are using XP, change your Explorer windows to Details View. Navigate to an SVN-controlled folder then go to View > Choose Details and select the SVN columns for status/rev/etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work in Vista or Windows 7 Beta. http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html

Comment: Working on Windows Server 2003 64Bit.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks John, that's very useful but doesn't show the revision for the root folder of a project.

Now that you've pointed me in the right direction, I have found that I can right-click the folder, select properties and a TortoiseSVN tab appears which contains the revision number.

Comment: Add this as a comment to his question then. You don't need to pretend this is an answer.

Comment: It is an answer. John's answer was not quite what I was looking for. This is.

Turns out that Dima submitted the same answer so I'll accept his.

Answer (score 0):

Before
"Change your Explorer windows to Details View. Navigate to an SVN-controlled folder then go to View > Choose Details and select the SVN columns for status/rev/etc."

you have to change your Windows Registry settings, adding this DWORD value

HKCU\Software\TortoiseSVN\ColumnsEveryWhere

and setting it to 1, as stated in the TortoiseSVN documentation.

Answer (score -1):

[nice one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89741/can-i-see-the-currently-checked-out-revision-number-in-tortoise-svn#89754) John Sheehan. I always just right clicked on the root folder and selected tortoise-svn | view log
.