# What does the Bold Type with Asterisk(*) in the SVN History mean?

Tags: svn

So I tried to see the project's svn history and noticed that it has a revision in bold type with (*). I have seen that earlier but never paid attention as it used to be the first entry in the history log. But this time it is not the case which brings me to question what does that mean and what is its purpose?

[image]

Comment: Last I checked, Subversion did not have a built-in GUI. What Subversion Client is this?

Comment: This is through the 'SVN Repository Exploring' perspective in RAD.

Comment: TortoiseSVN uses **bold** font in the same manner, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35669048/2932052

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the version you currently have updated your code to.

Comment: I do not fully understand what you mean. I do not see any Incoming changes when I Synchronize with the repository. There is nothing to update. Should that be a concern?

Comment: Well, now I understand..for some reasons the repository view was not updated and the Bold Type was pointing to older version that I updated to.

Comment: @Prince Perhaps "for some reasons" relates to ["this version resembles the current version in your workspace"](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/159305/)?  I am not sure how this works. I also have a fully synchronized workspace but the bold revision is not always the top one. Weird.

Comment: @datv Well, I think it just takes sometime for the workspace to completely synchronize.

Comment: To be precise: code means working copy. It seems you answer the *bold font* part here? But I don't know the SVN client the screenshot was taken from. Or does the asterisk mean the same?